# When to use inline backticks in documentation

Tags: documentation, backticks

When writing documentation, what things should be put in inline backticks?

For example I use inline backticks for the following,

- commands

  - E.g. "To run the program, run `python3 helloworld.py`"
- example output

  - E.g. "`python3 helloworld.py` should return `hello world`"
- specific kubernetes resources

  - E.g. "Every pod except `cache-deployer` should be running"

However, should I also use it for e.g. group membership?

- E.g. "User must be member of `leet_users`"

How do I do this consistently?